# JavaScript library similar to Imagemagick (i.e., resize images and pictures while maximizing picture fidelity)?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, imagemagick, flickr

We would like to simulate Imagemagick functionality, but only in Javascript. Do any libraries exist?

Specifically, the goal is to display thumbnails of images without distorting the thumbnail to the point where it is hardly resembles the original. This often happens with simple resizing via CSS.

One approach is to resize images on the server with Imagemagick.

The question is, if we don't want to store the thumbnails (because the originals are loaded from a third party which doesn't supply thumbnails), can we simulate Imagemagick's natural and high-fidelity resizing functionality with a Javascript library?

Thanks!

Comment: N. B. There is an Emscripten port of Imagemagick here: http://manuels.github.io/unix-toolbox.js/, but please don't use it if you dont *really* need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/reference/PImage_resize_) library. On the other hand you can port ImageMagick resize functionality to HTML5/Canvas + Javascript technology.

good luck !

Answer (score 18):

3 years later I stumbled upon this question ;)

The fun fact is that imagemagick itself exists in javascript.
But google (page1) and github somehow do not find it.
Github fails because the main project (useful emscripten ports)

> UNIX toolbox.js

just consists of the modules ...

Here is the main project with readme:
[github : manuels/unix-toolbox.js](https://github.com/manuels/unix-toolbox.js)

```
git clone ... --recursive
```

and the particular module :
[github : manuels/unix-toolbox.js-imagemagick](https://github.com/manuels/unix-toolbox.js-imagemagick)

Comment: life savior. Thanks for sharing