# Can a PNG be optimized in a browser via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, optimization, browser, png, image-compression

I have been using tools like [OptiPng](http://optipng.sourceforge.net/) for a long time and am wondering if there is any equivalent, that runs in JavaScript only inside the browser.

Just curious if a framework/plugin exists to optimize images in JavaScript?

Comment: you still will be sending a full image to the browser.

Comment: well, I assume at some point I will have a `data:image/png;base64,...` but I'm still wondering whether optimization can be done purely in the browser

Comment: I found pixtastic project. Not sure about performance but this sounds possible. http://www.pixastic.com/

Comment: @KevinLabécot: ah. nice direction. Mind posting as an answer?

Comment: this question is off topic as it is asking for a recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I found pixtastic project. Not sure about performance but this sounds possible. http://www.pixastic.com/

Answer (score 0):

Some thorough search later:

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343915/javascript-library-similar-to-imagemagick-i-e-resize-images-and-pictures-whil) has all the necessary links. There is an imageMagick version in Javascript (found [here](https://github.com/manuels/unix-toolbox.js-imagemagick)).

Also, in theory it's possible to port to Javascript using emscriptem (see [here](http://mozakai.blogspot.ch/2012/03/howto-port-cc-library-to-javascript.html))

[ProcessingJS](http://processingjs.org/reference/PImage_resize_/) also provides a resize method.

Enough to get started.